# Spring @Async abstraction is leaky regarding exception handling

Tags: java, spring

When using Spring's `@Async` annotation, the abstraction is leaky when it comes to (checked) exceptions in the `throws` clause of the method. The compiler will force the caller to handle the exception, but in actuality the caller will never see exceptions thrown by the `@Async` method. Instead, depending on the implementation, it will be handled & logged by Spring, or given to a user-configured exception handler, or produced when `Future#get()` is called on the return value.

Therefore, I am forming the opinion that `@Async` methods should, as a rule, never throw checked exceptions. Instead, they should wrap all checked exceptions in types of `RuntimeException` so that no `throws` clause is present.

Is this an accurate evaluation? Is there any tooling or programming approach that fixes the leak? Does anybody happen to know what the Spring developers think of this, or if there are any plans to improve the situation? Thanks!

Possibly related: [Spring Async method hides exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822257/spring-async-method-hides-exceptions)

Comment: Generally speaking, Spring prefers unchecked exceptions (look at the exception translation in Spring Data), and it's not really feasible for an async method to throw anything (which is why `Future` wraps exceptions).

Comment: The real problem starts when your @Async'ed method does not return any value. Some interesting things happen then ;)

Comment: What interesting things specifically, R4J?

Answer (score 2):

Your evaluation is probably correct.

Now, if you want to handle the said exception, just do this:

```
@Async
void mangle() {
    try {
        doMangle();
    } catch (YourCheckedException e) {
        // Handle it
    }
}

void doMangle() throws YourCheckedException {
    ...
}
```